# C#:What does Func<> mean when used as return value of a method?

Tags: c#

What does the following method return ? An array of function returning HashSet ?

```
    internal override Func<HashSet<char>>[] GetCompactableCharSets()
    {
        return new Func<HashSet<char>>[0];
    }
```

Comment: Yes, and a zero-length one at that.

Answer (score 1):

> What does the following method return ?

By **signature**, this is a method that returns an array of functions with no arguments returning `HashSet<char>`.

The concrete **implementation** returns an empty array described above.

Comment: Hmm, wierd usually when you would return it as 

return new Func<HashSet<char>>[] { };

Why does the example from the question even work.

Comment: @Chris Let say we need to return `T[]`. Using `return new T[0]` or `return new T[] { }` is just a matter of taste - both are equivalent. And why do you think it should not be? Array.Lengh=0 is a valid value, same as List.Count=0 etc.

Comment: Oh, yeah that's size of the array, thought it was indexing:)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, returning an **empty** array of function returning HashSet.